# Suppressing A DLL Required to complete install dialog

Tags: c#, windows-installer, orca

I have a few MSIs that are all built the same way for our application(s).

By MSI I mean, the normal built in Windows Installer that comes shipped with VS2010.

On a few machines, particularly Windows 8 and above, when some of our clients *attempt* to install the application the MSI throws the following error:

[image: Windows Installer Package]

I know *why* the error is thrown (and I'm sure most of you viewing this post know why...it's due to to the lack of permission set on the "Read & Execute" option to the %TEMP% "AppData/Local/Temp" folder).

I am able to recreate the issue here on my end, but I need a way to suppress this error. I know how to fix it, but I would like someway where I could trap this dialog via Orca or something and then extract the MSI somewhere else?

I do not know if this is possible (Not really much of an Installer expert).

Any ideas to go about fixing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Where would your code to fix it go, and how would that code get loaded?  Wouldn't the lack of execute permission interfere with getting your error-handling code mapped into the process in the first place?

Comment: @BenVoigt, Well I was thinking that since this error gets thrown as soon as I double click on the MSI, the MSI itself must perform some sort of check before it extracts itself? I don't know if there is a way to trap that.

Comment: Use procmon or similar to find out whether this is before or after extraction. Point remains, if extraction fails or results in unrunnable configuration, how does your custom error handler run? Do you have some way to run it directly inside the MSI without extracting first?

Comment: Why do you think, that it's a lack of permissions for %temp%? Even non-admins have 'Full Control' for own %temp%. Do you have log?

Comment: @Vadim I don't have a log at the moment. But all of the links I've read through Google seem to point to that. I also recreated the issue on my local machine, by removing the option for "Read & Execute" and I got the same error.

Comment: Well, you could check security setting for your %temp% folder, or even add full control for 'everyone'. I'm quite sure, there can not be any security troubles with %temp%. Start with creation of logs :)

Comment: @Vadim I just made a FAQ stating to add adequate permission to the %temp% folder. All of the research states that this error cannot be trapped.

Comment: As far as i understood, you're able to reproduce the issue on Win 8. So, just create log. All information is stored there. If you want to solve the problem without log - just buy a cristal ball or ask a clairvoyant. There is no other way :)